# Search for all iBeacons and not just with specific UUID

Tags: core-location, ios7, ibeacon

Is it possible to search for all `iBeacons` which are nearby? I know it's possible to search `iBeacons` by UUID. But i want to find all `iBeacons` nearby.

Comment: The API does not allow for such a call for security reasons but I can see how this would be very interesting. One idea would be to reverse engineer the iBeacon specification, scan for all nearby peripherals, then see if the broadcasted advertisements are iBeacons. Unfortunately Apple has not released the iBeacon specification. But it seems that they use encoded information in the advertisement to create an iBeacon. Because UUIDs of iBeacons will be random its doubtful that you can determine if a peripheral is an iBeacon from the advertisement alone unless you are Apple.

Comment: I have a mac application that is useful for debugging but it can't run on iOS devices... You can find it here if you was interested: https://github.com/liamnichols/iBeaconScanner

Comment: I made an app that does run on iOS devices (requires jailbreak): http://www.malcolmhall.com/products/ibeaconscanner/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An iBeacon is a region, and has as defining property the UUID. Therefore, you can only search for the ones matching a UUID.
After you find one or more with a specific UUID, you can figure out which is closest using the delegate callbacks, where the beacons are stored in an array ordered by distance.

There is great sample code on this and also a pretty detailed WWDC video session: "What's new in Core Location"

Comment: I've also searched for some sample code. Where did you find this code at the dev-site?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action It's the 5th link from the top. You want to download the "Airlocate" sample.

Comment: I've written a very simple app that demonstrates how the iBeacons API works: https://github.com/nicktoumpelis/HiBeacons. Hope it's useful.

Comment: You can do this on Anroid but not iOS.  Here's a detailed discussion of why this is not possible on iOS: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Comment: @NickToumpelis I can't thank you enough. So many thx. That is extremely helpful for me. THX.

Answer (score 7):

iBeacons are higher-level constructs than regular BLE peripherals. From what can be determined from the Apple docs, beacons are tied to their service UUID.  i.e., a family of beacons is a "region" and a you go into and out of a region based on the range and visibility of a beacon to YOU, not the other way around. Unfortunately Apple has used the term region, which most of us probably associate with MapKit, so this is adding to the general confusion

Here's the bad news:  You can only scan for ProximityUUIDs that you know, there is no "wildcard" proximityUUID.  Additionally, CLBeacons don't expose the much in the way of lower level CoreBluetooth guts so if you want to find all beacons that happen to be near you, you'll have to use CoreBluetooth, scan for peripherals, then  look though the returned peripheries and query each one them to find beacons.  Of course Apple has neither registered (with the Bluetooth SIG) or (yet) published the iBeacon characteristics so, you'll need a BT sniffer to reverse engineer what constitutes an iBeacon from any other BLE device.

Comment: according to http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html it's not possible to identify a beacon using CoreBluetooth

Answer (score 5):

each APP would use it's own specific UUID, using the "major" and "minor" integer values to differentiate between beacons.

for example, the UUID would be associated with a chain of shops, major would identify the shop, and minor the aisle, or even a group of products.

scanning for unknown UUID's would not be very useful, as your app would not know what to do with the information.

the UUID is generated once and for all, using the "uuidgen" command in the terminal.

sadly there is no protocol to actually communicate with beacons, hence there is no standard to get the location of a beacon, or any other useful info.

it would have been so much better if we could open a connection to a beacon, usually the closest one, and obtain additional data from it, without having to be on the same WIFI network.

you either have to use bonjour to communicate with the device over WIFI, or use the major and minor id to obtain data from a webservice of some kind.

Comment: "scanning for unknown UUID's would not be very useful, as your app would not know what to do with the information." That is horribly false as sometimes one needs to see all beacons without any context

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you cannot at this time search for an arbitrary iBeacon without first knowing the proximityUUID value. I've tried writing directly to COREBluetooth and, although you can discover and connect to transmitting beacons in your area, what you get back is jibberish with no relation to the BLE UUID. So you can't even confirm that the peripheral you have connected to is in fact an iBeacon.

This does not appear to be a limitation of the BLE spec, rather it is a limitation that has been imposed by Apple. It also appears that this limitation does not exist for the Android platform.

Until this gap is closed, Android will have a significant advantage over iOS in this area.

I disagree with previous comments that scanning for UUIDs would be useless. On the contrary, if you knew the beacon UUID, you could create a map of beacon/location/subject in the cloud and use it to navigate (assuming the beacon was fixed) using a web service. You could crowd-source the data so that eventually a very rich database of beacon UUID/location pairs would be available to all who wanted to write location apps. Perhaps this is why Apple is hiding the info; they may be holding this back for their own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

According to Radius Networks (authors of the [AltBeacon](http://altbeacon.org/) spec and the [android-beacon-library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/documentation.html) [it's not possible to identify a beacon using CoreBluetooth](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html)