# How to search for iBeacons UUID, and scan for all iBeacons around in iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ibeacon

I am working on an iOS app that detects iBeacon devices around me.
From what I understand, we need to know the specific UUID to scan for them.

for ex here: [Search for all iBeacons and not just with specific UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784285/search-for-all-ibeacons-and-not-just-with-specific-uuid)

With this in mind, I use corelocation and I can detect my beacons, ok!

Problem is, when I try several apps in the AppStore, some of the app can just scan all of my beacons with different UUID (I have more than 90 beacons with 8 different UUIDs)!! how is it possible??

App 1: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ebeacon/id730279939?mt=8

App 2:https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/dartle-ibeacon-locator/id904211297?l=en&mt=8

So my first thought is that they use some kind of private framework from Apple, but if you do that, your app will not allow to be published!, hmmmm...

So my question is, how can they do that?
- Do they have like a list of all UUID from all the iBeacon manufacturers?
- Or they know a way to scan for all surrounding iBeacons UUID?

Can someone pls help me answer the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple's intention is that you *can't* find all beacons around you, mostly for privacy reasons, but also to save power. Your app should only work with specific beacons, so you need to set up all *your* beacons so your app recognises them. You shouldn't be able to detect the beacons that *my* app uses. So the presence of a beacon will only be detected if the user explicitly downloads and runs an app that is supposed to detect that beacon.

BTW. If you buy beacons, they should come with an application (usually a Mac or Windows application) that lets you change their ID. So if Joe's Carwash application uses beacons, Joe buys 100 beacons, and then sets them all up to he ID that Joe's Carwash app recognises. Otherwise Joe would be in real trouble if a beacon breaks, needs replacing, and then Joe needs to update his app. Instead if a beacon breaks that was set to ID xxxxx, Joe buys a new beacons, changes its ID to xxxxx, and puts it where the previous beacon was.

Comment: Thank you, I just do more testing, it seems like on Android, you can scan for all available beacons around, but not for Apple. That is mean the other app get to know more manufacturer UUID to be able to detect them. 
Do you know any of those resources?